# How to get the accurate amount of bids?

Tags: offer

An orderbook call of an asset pair returns `bids` as, for example:

```
amount: "599.3762459"
price: "0.0599376"
price_r:
d: 10427507
n: 625000
```

where the `amount` should be `10,000`. Whereas, `asks` are returned as:

```
amount: "10000.0000000"
price: "0.0601957"
price_r:
d: 10000000
n: 601957
```

accurately reflecting the `amount`.

How does one compute or get the accurate bid amount? I tried all sorts of multiplication and division with big numbers but I could not quite get to an accurate `10,000` for the bid.

(The asset pair is `XLM` [`native`] and `USD` [`GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX`].)

Comment: What do you mean by "an accurate 10,000 for the bid"?

Comment: @kolten In the order book, I should display the bid amount as 10,000, not 599.3762459. How do I manipulate the given figures in the bid data to arrive at 10,000?

Comment: Wouldn't the bid and ask amounts be different? The orderbooks don't generally mirror each other in that way.

Comment: If you look at the pair at stellarport, for example, the bid amount is reflected as 10,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that Stellar offers amount is always [quoted in the amount of the selling asset](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/offer.html).

When you are selling 10000 XLM for USD the ask offers shows 10000 as expected, since you are selling XLM.

When you are buying 10000 XLM for USD, it is effectively an offer to sell USD for XLM. The amount of USD is given by the XLM amount times the price, or `10000 * (625000/10427507) = 599.3762459234`.

Comment: Good point actually.